# how to fork a repository in mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I have a mercurail repo sg and it's path is https://merc.server.repo.com/hg/CS/sg/
if i clone it and check for branch , i get default branch as the master branch.

hg branch

default

I want to fork this repo and create another repo sg1 from this repo and path should be https://merc.server.repo.com/hg/CS/sg1/
And when for new repo i do "hg branch" ,it should be same results. That is "default" should be the master branch in new repo as well.

hg branch

default

I do not have the login for the mercurial server. How can i do this? 
Also we are not using guthub /bitbucket etc.
Any suggestions are welcome. If you can provide steps that would be really helpful.

Comment: Forking is as simple as cloning the repo. When it comes to creating the fork on your server, that depends on the software your server runs - especially if you have no access to the server... a login would greatly help. Otherwise make sure that you have the server run a software like kallithea. But that likely falls under 'github, bitbucket, etc'.

Comment: What is the server software?

Comment: [tag:fork] is a wrong tag, as it refers to the `fork` system call on Unix / Linux. (I've deleted it here.)  A Git "fork" is really just a clone, except that some web servers do additional linking behind the scenes to make it more convenient for you to communicate with the owners of the repository you cloned. Whether your server does this same thing for Mercurial repositories, and if so, how, is up to your server.